# How can I create a MFA Auth Flow for user login to Azure AD using only WPF/C# controls - no browser is available

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-iot-central

I need to create a simple two factor auth flow for users to log in to Azure Ad and retrieve device keys from IoT Central.  The devices don't have browsers available - are there any examples of the auth flow for user to log in and then be prompted to enter a token on the Microsoft Authenticator app ?  Basically the same flow as a browser.

What APIs and C# SDK would one use for .Net Framework 4.7 ?  The options all seem to target .net rather than .net framework.

Comment: Hope this reference  [MSDOC](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-device-code.md) [helps](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/active-directory/develop/scenario-desktop-acquire-token-device-code-flow.md)

Comment: I found a solution - see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76980736/how-can-i-authenticate-a-user-from-a-wpf-c-application-without-using-the-browse

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76980736/how-can-i-authenticate-a-user-from-a-wpf-c-application-without-using-the-browse