# How can I authenticate a user from a WPF/C# application without using the Browser UI?

Tags: azure-active-directory

I am trying to authentic a user with Azure AD using MFA from a WFP/C# application without using the browser - so with a custom WPF user interface.

AWS Cognito provides an auth/challenge flow where the user logs in, Cognito sends a token to their mobile phone and challenges for the user to input the token.

Is there a similar auth flow available from Azure AD and if so where can I find an example that allows use of a custom WPF/C# user interface.

The device does not have access to a browser.  All the examples I can find seem to invoke a browser to do the authentication in conjunction with the Microsoft Authenticator app on a phone.  This would be fine as I would expect we would present the Authenticator number in the WPF UI and the user would accept on their phone.

Below is an example of the Auth/Challenge flow - is this possible with Azure AD ?

As an alternative how could I use an embedded WebView2 component for the browser based authentication ?

```
 private void LoginUsingWPFUI()
 {

     string username = "xxxx";  // Obtained from UI

     string password = "Password";  // Obtained from UI

     var AuthService = AuthService("TenantID", "Otherparams..");

     AuthService.ChallengeCallback = ChallengeCallback;

     // Login using username and password

     var result = LoginToAzureADWorkAccount(username, password);


 }

 public void ChallengeCallback(AuthChallenge challenge)
 {
     switch (challenge.Token)
     {
         case "PresentTokenToUser";
             ShowToken(challenge.Token);
             // Auth Challenge
             break;
         case "ChallengeAcceptedHideToken":
             HideToken();
             // Login sucessfull
             break;
         default:
             // Login failed...
             break;
     }
       
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK finally I found this example specifically for Device code to acquire a token.  The device displays a code and the user needs to go to the https://microsoft.com/devicelogin web page where they are prompted to enter the code displayed on the device.

This then asks for them to login using their Azure AD account using the normal auth methods.

Neat as there is no need to enter anything at all into the device.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-desktop-acquire-token-device-code-flow?tabs=dotnet